# Given a geographical coordinate in U.S., how to find out if it is in Urban or Rural areas?

Tags: geospatial, shapefile, shapely, pyshp

Given a geographical coordinate in U.S., how to find out if it is in Urban or Rural areas?

I have about 10000 geographical coordinates all in the U.S., and I want to use Python + basemap to find out if a point is urban or rural.

I'm not sure which library or shape file to use.

I'll need a function like this:

```
def is_urban(coordinate):
  # use the shapefile
  urban = False
  return urban
```

Comment: You could for sure use over() methods in R out of the sp package, but I realize that isn't what you asked for (python). The R method would be to find the urban rural classifications, which are likely in the tiger shapefiles from the US census. SpatialPoints your coordinates -> over() using sp.

Comment: Edit to above since I forgot rgdal in R: SpatialPoints your coordinates -> load shapefile using readOGR from rgdal,  over() using sp. The tiger shapefiles would still probably be your best bet in python. Hope this helps a little!

Comment: do you have a dataset that delineates urban vs rural areas?

Comment: This is the urban areas shape file, so if a point is not inside these, it's rural. https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_ua.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while [Ash's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/956730/ash) comment does get the job done, iterating over the shapes individually is slow, in O(N) time

you can use geopandas to put the shapes into GeoDataFrames, then use sjoin to do a spatial join on the data. geopandas uses trees for this function, so it executes in roughly O(log(n)) time.

instead of several seconds  per query, now it's several milliseconds per query, on my machine.(7+ s VS 3 ms)

here's my code:

```
import shapefile
import geopandas as gpd
shp = shapefile.Reader('tl_rd22_us_uac20.shp') #open the shapefile
all_shapes = shp.shapes() # get all the polygons
all_records = shp.records()
polygons_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=all_shapes) #convert the polygons into a geodataframe

class Address():
    longitude = None
    latitude = None
    def __init__(self, long, lat):
        self.longitude = long
        self.latitude = lat


def is_urban(addr):
    result = False
    points_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy([addr.longitude], [addr.latitude]))  # point coordinates to geopandas dataframe
    pt2poly = gpd.sjoin(points_gpd,polygons_gpd, predicate='within').index_right  # for each point index in the points, it stores the polygon index containing that point
    if len(pt2poly) >= 1:  # if any indicies are found, it's urban
        result = True
        print('urban')
    else:
        print('rural')
    return result

pt = Address(-87.6298, 41.8781) # Chicago, Il
is_urban(pt)
# prints 'urban'
```

in addition, the link Ash provided is no longer valid.  As of December 2023, you can get the shapefiles from https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_RD18/LAYER/UAC20/

Answer (score 6):

```
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import Point # Point class
from shapely.geometry import shape # shape() is a function to convert geo objects through the interface

pt = (-97.759615,30.258773) # an x,y tuple
shp = shapefile.Reader('/home/af/Downloads/cb_2016_us_ua10_500k/cb_2016_us_ua10_500k.shp') #open the shapefile
all_shapes = shp.shapes() # get all the polygons
all_records = shp.records()

def is_urban(pt):
    result = False
    for i in range(len(all_shapes)):
        boundary = all_shapes[i] # get a boundary polygon
        #name = all_records[i][3] + ', ' + all_records[i][4] # get the second field of the corresponding record
        if Point(pt).within(shape(boundary)): # make a point and see if it's in the polygon
            result = True
    return result

result = is_urban(pt)
```

I ended up using shapely and shapefile downloaded from 
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_ua.html, which has urban areas of the U.S., so if a point is not within any of these areas, it's rural.

I tested it, and it works to my expectation.